# Mockito - test method without inner method

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testng, mockito

I have the following class

```
public class EmailManager{

  protected String getEmailContent(String content,String image){
     String result = content.toPrettyLook(); //this is an inner method
     result+="<img src='" + +"' />";
     return result;
  }

  protected String getImageLocation(String image){
      //write image to disc
      return newLocation;
  } 
}

public class EmailManagerTest{

  EmailManager emailManager;

  @Test
  public void testEmailContent(){
     String result = emailManager.getEmailContent("Hello World");
  }
}
```

1. What annotation should I put above EmailManager? @Spy @Mock or
   @Autowired?
2. How can I tell Mockito not to execute getImageLocation (the method that is being called by getEmailContent) and always
   returns instead of it "new location"? I saw many articles and got
   confused between "when" "stub" "doReturn"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want here is a Spy : a partially mocked object. You want to test the real `getEmailContent()` method, but you want to stub the `getImageLocation()` method of the same object. So the test should look like

```
public class EmailManagerTest{

    private EmailManager emailManager;

    @Test
    public void testEmailContent(){
        emailManager = spy(new EmailManager());
        doReturn("new location").when(emailManager).getImageLocation("someImage");
        String result = emailManager.getEmailContent("Hello World", "someImage");
        // assertions ...
    }
}
```

If you want to use annotations to let Mockito create the spy for you, then you can use the Spy annotation:

```
@Spy
private EmailManager emailManager = new EmailManager();
```

Don't forget to add a @Before method which calls `MockitoAnnotations.initClass(this)`.

Mockito is very well documented. Read [the documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html).

Comment: I tried your code, but the method getImageLocation is being executed! any reason?